# How do I track Google account logins on python GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-analytics, google-cloud-platform

I'm building a Google App Engine app with Google Account logins. I am hoping that some kind of reporting on user logins already exists in Google App Engine without setting up tags in Google Analytics.  Does this type of reporting exist somewhere in Google Cloud Console?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that something similar already out of the box exist in Cloud Console without using Analytics.

Maybe you can have a look at Firebase which will be the new platform for building Apps. I think that they have already something like User Tracking integrated

Regards

Michael